# Como definir horário para modo silencioso

Tags: java, android

Tenho um app de horário escolar e coloquei a opção de silenciar o dispositivo durante o tempo estipulado pelo usuário. No entanto há apenas a opção de ativar e desativar o modo silêncioso, como posso fazer isso de maneira automática de acordo com o horário selecionado e o horário do relógio?

Comment: Você fez um app ou você está usando um app que nao foi desenvolvido por você? Não ficou claro pra mim.

Comment: Eu que fiz,totalmente programado e desenvolvido por mim,legal! ;)

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor, não estou entendendo o que está feito e qual é o problema.

Comment: De uma olhada na classe [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), ela permite que você agende tarefas para serem executadas em algum momento do futuro, mesmo que sua aplicação não esteja mais rodando e o aparelho não esteja "acordado". Você precisará de uma intenção para colocar o celular em modo silencioso e outra para retorná-lo à configuração anterior.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Você quer dizer interação em vez de intenção?

Comment: Quis dizer intenção mesmo (de [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), um conceito do Android). Deveria ter explicado melhor mas o sono não está deixando hehehe. Se ninguém elaborar amanhã eu faço isso.

Comment: Ah, certo. Eu não sei nada de Android.

Comment: Sua pergunta então é: como ativar e desativar o modo silencioso de forma programática?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi é só um timer a partir das horas, não?

Comment: @Felipe, o `Timer` é uma boa opção para coisas que vão rodar frequentemente enquanto o aplicativo está aberto; para agendar tasks esporádicas em background o `AlarmManager` é mais recomendado. Veja [esse artigo](http://vikinghammer.com/2012/04/22/android-use-alarmmanager-instead-of-a-service-with-a-timertask/) (em inglês). Com o o autor do artigo eu já tive problemas com consumo de recursos e bateria devido ao uso incorreto de `Timer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se seu problema é agendar atividades no Android a melhor classe é o

### [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Segue abaixo trecho explicativo de um exemplo,
para ver o exemplo completo acesse:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

---

Na sua Activity declare as seguintes variáveis de classe:

```
PendingIntent pi;
BroadcastReceiver br;
AlarmManager am;
AudioManager audio;
```

Crie um método privado para configurar o seu agendador. Instanciar as variaveis e definir o broadcast receiver que vai receber o callback quando o evento acontecer.

```
private void setup() {
      br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
                    // Escreva aqui o que deve ser executando quando o evento acontecer
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Entrando em modo silencioso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Modo Silencioso
                    audio = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
             }
      };
      registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.seuprojeto.suaactivity") );
      pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.seuprojeto.suaactivity"),
0 );
      am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
}
```

Chame o método setup no onCreate da Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setup();
    ...
}
```

Set o AlarmManager no listener do seu botão:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    long seuTempo = 1000 * 20; // 20 segundos
    am.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + seuTempo, pi );
}
```

---

Siga para o exemplo completo no link:

### http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Comment: Eu não poderia ter escrito melhor. Só o que tenho a completar é que existem diversos outros tipos de alarme (por exemplo `RTC_WAKEUP` te permite executar um alarme em determinado horário mesmo que o aparelho esteja dormindo). Assim, você pode ir muito além do "coloque em modo silencioso daqui a 20 segundos". Você pode por exemplo construir um alarme para colocar o celular em modo silencioso as `X` horas e outro para retorná-lo ao modo anterior `Y` tempo depois. Inclusive pode aplicar [repetições](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) (de `Z` em `Z` tempo).